# ¿Por qué mi aplicación no encuentra una web cuando es lanzada por una tarea?

Tags: c#, proxy, app.config

Tengo una aplicación en C# que descarga un fichero .txt desde una web utilizando la clase WebClient.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(url, ruta);
```

Al lanzar la aplicación de forma manual, el archivo se descarga correctamente y no hay ningún problema. Sin embargo, si creo una tarea programada que lanza la aplicación, la aplicación no consigue llegar a la URL, y salta el siguiente error:

No se puede resolver el nombre remoto: '...'

En el AppConfig tengo añadido lo siguiente:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

No entiendo qué puede estar funcionando mal.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Buenas Asier, debes añadir mas información a tu pregunta para poder ver que problema puede haber, faltaria saber que lleva las ariables que mencionas arriba `url` y `ruta` por ejemplo.

Comment: Buenas, la url es sólo accesible desde nuestra red local así que no vale de nada que la muestre... pero vamos,`url` lleva a un documento .txt normal, y `ruta` es una ruta que existe en el pc, y todo funciona correctamente cuando ejecuto el automatismo de forma manual. El problema está cuando es una tarea programada quien lo lanza.

Comment: Parece extraño el error que describes. Podría estar provocado por algun error en la red local, con el dns...(has probado a hacer un par de reintentos cuando recibas esa excepción?). Pero que te funcione lanzandolo normalmente, y no como tarea programada es raro, no debería haber ninguna diferencia...De todas maneras, comprueba que cuenta está usando la tarea programada para lanzar la app

Comment: Hola. La tarea programada es ejecutada por la misma cuenta de usuario que la manual? Puede ser por eso, tema de permisos. Un saludo